# GCC 5.2 Error with cc1, cc1plus

Tags: c++, c, gcc, centos

I received the following error while making GCC 5.2 for CentOS 7.  I had added a few files to make it work, libstdc++-devel, ccache along with running the 'download prerequisites' command.  Below is what happened before the error message appeared.

```
 cp/cp-lang.o c-family/stub-objc.o cp/call.o cp/decl.o cp/expr.o cp/pt.o 
 cp/typeck2.o cp/class.o cp/decl2.o cp/error.o cp/lex.o cp/parser.o 
 cp/ptree.o cp/rtti.o cp/typeck.o cp/cvt.o cp/except.o cp/friend.o 
 cp/init.o cp/method.o cp/search.o cp/semantics.o cp/tree.o cp/repo.o 
 cp/dump.o cp/optimize.o cp/mangle.o cp/cp-objcp-common.o cp/name-lookup.o 
 cp/cxx-pretty-print.o cp/cp-cilkplus.o cp/cp-gimplify.o cp/cp-array-notation.o
 cp/lambda.o cp/vtable-class-hierarchy.o cp/constexpr.o cp/cp-ubsan.o
 attribs.o incpath.o c-family/c-common.o c-family/c-cppbuiltin.o c-family/c-dump.o 
 c-family/c-format.o c-family/c-gimplify.o c-family/c-lex.o 
 c-family/c-omp.o c-family/c-opts.o c-family/c-pch.o c-family/c-ppoutput.o 
 c-family/c-pragma.o c-family/c-pretty-print.o c-family/c-semantics.o c-family/c-ada-spec.o 
 c-family/c-cilkplus.o c-family/array-notation-common.o c-family/cilk.o 
 c-family/c-ubsan.o i386-c.o glibc-c.o cc1plus-checksum.o libbackend.a main.o  
 libcommon-target.a libcommon.a ../libcpp/libcpp.a ../libdecnumber
 /libdecnumber.a libcommon.a ../libcpp/libcpp.a   ../libbacktrace/.libs
 /libbacktrace.a ../libiberty/libiberty.a 
 ../libdecnumber/libdecnumber.a   -lmpc -lmpfr -lgmp -rdynamic -ldl  -L../zlib -lz
```

EDIT...(process before error)

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [cc1plus] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[3]: *** [cc1] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/gcc-5.2/gcc-5.2.0/objdir/gcc'
make[2]: *** [all-stage3-gcc] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/gcc-5.2/gcc-5.2.0/objdir'
make[1]: *** [stage3-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/gcc-5.2/gcc-5.2.0/objdir'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

From the `config.log` file (ADDED)

```
 configure:5989: checking for compatible ISL
 configure:6002: gcc -msse2 -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -o conftest -g -O2
  -lisl conftest.c  -lisl >&5
 conftest.c:10:21: fatal error: isl/val.h: No such file or directory
 #include <isl/val.h>
```

Various searches through the Google, have not turned anything up.  Most errors had a particular error with the cc1 Error, while my setup just output "Leaving Directory".  Looking through the potential errors on the GCC webpage did not turn up anything.  I had setup the compile file with with the following settings.  Thank you for your help.

```
/usr/local/gcc-5.2/gcc-5.2.0/configure --prefix=/usr/local/sbin/gcc-5.2.0
--enable-languages=c,c++  --disable-multilib
```

Comment: Looks like you cut out the interesting parts of the output.

Comment: Please post the part where `ld` tells you which shared object has issues.

Comment: Exit `1` means `ld` didn't complete successfully, but you didn't include the error. `Error 1` means `operation not permitted`. This would mean the `cc1plus` is unable to do its job. This is probably caused by `ld` unable to do what it needed to do.  `Error 2` means `no such file or directory`. This is the result of the next command due to `ld` not producing an output.

Comment: That's a pretty odd `--prefix`. `*/sbin` is normally used for sysadmin tools, not regular user binaries..

Comment: @iharob, Ok, I forgot to put the config.log file info on here.  Sorry, a little rusty with stackoverflow.

Comment: Do you have development package for `isl`? perhaps `libisl-devel`.

Comment: @iharob, I was looking through `yum provides */isl` and found nothing...  I also tried `yum provides */libisl` and `yum install libisl-devel` with no results.

Comment: You can download [libisl-0.14.1.tar.xz](http://isl.gforge.inria.fr/isl-0.14.1.tar.xz) and compile it from source too. I recommend you take a look at [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) it could help you a lot in this kind of task.

Comment: @iharob, I wasn't sure if I needed isl, since after compiling, it still did not register.  But, I got it to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change my `./configure` setup and read [Linux from Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org).  With help from @iharob, I was able to compile GCC.  Below is the new `./configure` setup.

```
/usr/local/gcc-5.2/gcc-5.2.0/configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc-5.2/gcc-5.2.0/objdir 
--enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-threads=posix --disable-multilib 
--disable-nls --disable-bootstrap LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

I may have not needed the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` flag, but I played it safe.